# Install MySQL on SSD, best mount options?

Tags: mysql, performance, mount, ssd

I want to install the mysql-server on my SSD, what are the best mount options for this? (/etc/fstab)

What else I can do to increase the SSD Speed?

My current configuration:

```
/dev/sdc /ssd ext4 errors=remount-ro,noatime,nodiratime,discard 0 0
```

I installed first the package via apt-get and after I changed in the my.cnf the datadir to the ssd.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Best mount options" is like asking for the "best flavor of pizza."  Different mount options provide different functionality (obviously!).  You should read the mount(8) man page, for a description of all the various mount options, for your file system.

[This blog](https://blog.smartlogic.io/2009-06-04-rails-development-mount-options-to-improve-ext4-file-system-performance/) provides several speed-optimizing mount options you might consider, and explains some of the risks of using some of them.

Really, I don't think there's much difference between the mount options you would use for an SSD versus a traditional hard drive--except that there should be much less need to care at all for an SSD, since it's already much faster--especially for random seeks.  So things like 'noatime', while they will likely improve performance on an SSD, will probably improve it almost imperceptibly, compared to a physical disk, where writing a single 'atime' record is a lot more expensive, relatively speaking.